# Creating react application using typescript facing issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Error is:

**G:\ReactProj\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239
appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = value;
^
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'jsx' of object '#'
at verifyTypeScriptSetup (G:\ReactProj\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239:43)
at Object. (G:\ReactProj\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:31:1)**

Sharing my error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\lionh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v15.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~prestart: my-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: my-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\lionh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;G:\ReactProj\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\lionh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\lionh\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\lionh\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\lionh\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: G:\ReactProj\my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lionh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:329:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lionh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:329:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd G:\ReactProj\my-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\lionh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v15.2.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and my tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a new project? 
I very very much recommend using create-react-app with the typescript presets. That should work without any mayor issues.

Comment: yes, i am creating a new project.i did the same way as it is suggested in React website

Comment: What command is giving you error, is it npm install or npm run start?

Comment: i used the npm start command

Comment: have you run npm/yarn install?

Comment: i have created my app using 
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

Answer (score 1):

Found solution
[React 17 jsx typesceipt issue](https://dev.to/ebonynon/react-17-jsx-react-scripts-with-typescript-30ap)

this worked for me but Typescript/react team definitely needs to solve this problem asap